# Group variables and loop through them

Tags: php, wordpress

When I just had single variables I used the `compact` array function to create an array containing variables and their values and looped through them, but now I have multiple variables in a 'group' to loop through:

```
$details_room_name_1
$details_room_photo_1
$details_room_capacity_seated_1

$details_room_name_2
$details_room_photo_2
$details_room_capacity_seated_2

$details_room_name_2
$details_room_photo_2
$details_room_capacity_seated_2
```

I want to loop through each 'GROUP' (room) of variables at a time

```
loop
  echo room name
  print_r room photo array
  echo capacity
```

Comment: You tagged this `arrays` and yet you're not using them. Of course, you should be and this would be trivial if you did.

Comment: @JohnConde Wish I could.. these are wordpress custom fields (ACF) and I don't have control over it.

Comment: Why isn't this tagged with `wordpress` then? Wouldn't that be relevant?

Comment: Added it, if it helps. I just mentioned wordpress to state that I don't have control over creating the variables.

Comment: I'm interested in how you have no control over how variables are created. Of course you do, it is your website, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using array is better (the best) solution for this task, but if the data structure has to be as you wrote (I don´t know Wordpress), you can use st. like this ugly code.

```
<?php

$details_room_name_1 = 'room 1';
$details_room_photo_1 = 'photo 1';
$details_room_capacity_seated_1 = 1;

$details_room_name_2 = 'room 2';
$details_room_photo_2 = 'photo 2';
$details_room_capacity_seated_2 = 5;

$details_room_name_3 = 'room 3';
$details_room_photo_3 = 'photo 3';
$details_room_capacity_seated_3 = 8;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    if (!isset(${'details_room_name_' . $i})) continue;

    echo 'room name: ' . ${'details_room_name_' . $i} . '<br>';
    echo 'room photo: ' . ${'details_room_photo_' . $i} . '<br>';
    echo 'room capacity: ' . ${'details_room_capacity_seated_' . $i} . '<br><br>';
}

/*
    returns

    room name: room 1
    room photo: photo 1
    room capacity: 1

    room name: room 2
    room photo: photo 2
    room capacity: 5

    room name: room 3
    room photo: photo 3
    room capacity: 8
*/
```

Comment: hmm..but counting to a fixed integer `3` is not ideal

Comment: Sure, there is a `for` loop, you don't know how many items/rooms you have? It's not array, so you can't use `foreach`.

Comment: how about `if ( !empty(${'accommodation_room_name_' . $i}) )` inside the loop?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Added higher limit into the loop (`10`) and use `continue` when variable doesn't exist.

Comment: How about creating an array of rooms instead of individuals objects like you have? Surely wordpress is not the one creating all these variables...

Comment: @ElefantPhace It is. Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

Comment: @panther quite strangely, nothing is printed at all. maybe the ${} syntax is not supported in my version of php? No errors, but doesn't print anything either.

Comment: @Nimbuz: not sure, I have PHP 5.4.4 and it works me fine, and 7 years ago it works too, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php#73373

Comment: Whatever plugin you're using, you can still control variable creation. Sorry if you have to edit some code to fit your needs, but that's not what we are here for...

Comment: @Nimbuz: what about variable names? It question you have `$details_...`, in comment above you have `$accomodation_...`. Just typo?

Comment: @panther no thats another group of vars, I double checked everything.

Comment: @Nimbuz: sorry, no idea. When I copy my code to http://phpfiddle.org/, I get the same result as on my local server. You can try it, it should return you the same result as me. Than it can depends on any PHP/Apache settings. Probably, I don´t know.

Comment: Yes, its definitely something on my end. Thanks a ton though! :)