# How to nest variables and loop through sub-variables in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, loops

I am trying to write a script that generates csv files from mysql. The csv files from mysql is working fine, however, I'm struggling with a way to loop through variables, or treat them as an array to loop through.

Some example variables are below

```
c1="Client 1"
c1_s1_name=Alpha
c1_s1_id=761967
c1_s2_name=Beta
c1_s2_id=415612

c2="Client 2"
c2_s1_name=XYZ
c2_s1_id=438976
c2_s2_name=ABC
c2_s2_id=982012

c3="Client 3"
c3_s1_name=No-Name
c3_s1_id=347654
c3_s2_name=House
c3_s2_id=109321
```

I then have some quasi-code that attempts to run a sql script for each  `client` as below but

```
# loop through all clients
for all_clients in $c1 $c2 $c3
do

# and then loop through for all survey names and all survey ids for each seperate client
for survey_name in $*_name and survey_id in $*_id
do
mysql -h "localhost" -u "root" "$DATABASE" -e "SELECT count(*) FROM $survey_id" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > $all_clients-$survey_name-filename-count.csv
done

done
```

I'm not sure how to set the script up so that the `c1` variables are run as a set and then `c2`, followed by `c3`. I'm guessing an array might be what I need but I'm not sure?

I've also come across the answer below but it's for PHP, even though it looks suspiciously like bash...

[Group variables and loop through them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054255/group-variables-and-loop-through-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build the name of your dynamic variable and then dereference it with the `{!var}` syntax. Granted that you know your variable names in advance (i.e. the first part is always `c1`, `c2` or `c3`, the second part is always `s1` or `s2`, …), you can use something like that:

```
for x in c1 c2 c3; do
  for y in s1 s2; do
    for z in name id; do
      xyz=${x}_${y}_${z}
      # Use ${!xyz} to get the contents of the variable
    done
  done
done
```

[Example](https://repl.it/repls/AuthorizedDownrightEyestrain) (but without your mysql call, obviously)

I have used `x`, `y` and `z` to emphasize how the variable is constructed, but
you can replace `x` by `all_clients`, etc..

You can use a slightly more advanced technique if the number of `c*` and `s*` is not known in advance.

```
numc=3
nums=2
for x in $(seq -f 'c%g' $numc); do
  for y in $(seq -f 's%g' $nums); do
    for z in name id; do
      xyz=${x}_${y}_${z}
      # Use ${!xyz} to get the contents of the variable
    done
  done
done
```

[Example](https://repl.it/repls/MediumorchidClearcutDeclaration)

The magic here is from [`seq`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/seq). For example, in the following call:

```
seq -f 'c%g' $numc
```

The `$numc` option says you want to iterate from `1` to `$numc`. The `-f 'c%g'` option says that you want to form a `printf`-like string, in this case the letter `c` followed by the numeric value. So, the above example will write:

```
c1
c2
c3
```

The whole string is captured by `$()` which means the output will be inlined in your script. All in all, the following line:

```
for x in $(seq -f 'c%g' $numc); do
```

Will be interpreted as:

```
for x in c1 c2 c3; do
```

Which is equivalent to the initial `for` loop, except that now you control the number of iterations.

Comment: **You can use a slightly more advanced technique if the number of c* and s* is not known in advance** This looks really useful as the number of `c*` and `s*` will be unknown going forward but I don't understand the role of `numc=3` and `nums=2` above?

Comment: This is an example of the value coming from somewhere else, in this case I have simply defined a variable. You can get the number by any means you want: from a file, read an input from the user, etc. e.g. `read -p "Please enter the number of c: " numc` will ask the user to type a number from the keyboard and store it in the variable `numc`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!